# Facebook sharer shows blank window and manual sharing doesn't give any preview

Tags: facebook, sharing

I have a strange problem on my site with Facebook sharing. "Like" is working fine but I can't share any url with oficial buttons. The sharer.php returns a blank window. When i try to share an url manually it doesn't show any preview but url.

This started today. Nothing changed on the site.

I've tried debug tool on Facebook but it seems everything is fine. I don't get any error or warning.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Give us a url of your page with fb buttons, or at least a URL you invoke share window, so you could be helped.

Comment: URL: http://www.gercekgundem.com/medya/15164/erdogan-ataturkun-sozlerini-soylerse

Comment: Facebook responses with 500 Internal server error. Either wait what will happen in next days, or somebody may provide you with further info